# Slow query with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, indexing, performance

I am getting some slowness (~6s) when I run the following query:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache
    t1.id, t2.id, count(injury.id)
FROM age_group as t1
CROSS JOIN body_part as t2
LEFT JOIN injury 
     ON t1.id = injury.age_group_id 
     AND t2.id = injury.body_part_id
GROUP BY t1.id,t2.id
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` then it executes quickly.

When I use `EXPLAIN` the only difference is with the `GROUP BY` is it lists "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort".

I'm at a loss as to how to avoid this.

We needed to be able to group on any of the fields in the injury table so indexing every combination is likely not a good solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the aggregation without the join:

```
select injury.age_group_id, injury.body_part_id, count(*)
from injury
group by injury.age_group_id, injury.body_part_id
```

This will only return results where there are injuries.

If this performs well, then do the join afterwards:

```
select t.id, t2.id, coalesce(injury.cnt, 0)
from age_group as t1 CROSS JOIN
     body_part as t2 left outer join
     (select injury.age_group_id, injury.body_part_id, count(*) as cnt
      from injury
      group by injury.age_group_id, injury.body_part_id
     ) injury LEFT JOIN
     injury ON t1.id = injury.age_group_id and t2.id = injury.body_part_id
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'm unsure why it is faster. EXPLAIN still shows "Using temporary; Using filesort" which was my understanding of why my query was slow. I thought it was because of result table only had three columns but if altered it to include all columns but it was still just as fast.

Comment: @user2449882 . . . I think the reason is because it is doing the aggregation before the join, so the data size is smaller.